# Where does this syntax error in my PySide2 script come from?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyside2

I'm writing a script to load and display a QML file using the PySide2 library for python. Currently, the following script **works:**

```py
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PySide2.QtQuick import QQuickView
from PySide2.QtCore import QUrl
import sys

app = QApplication([])
qml_url = QUrl(sys.argv[0])
view = QQuickView()
```

However, when I add the next line:

```py
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PySide2.QtQuick import QQuickView
from PySide2.QtCore import QUrl
import sys

app = QApplication([])
qml_url = QUrl(sys.argv[0])
view = QQuickView()
view.setSource(qml_url)
```

I get the following error:

```
test.py:1:6: Syntax error 
     from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication
          ^
```

I know there are alternative libraries and methods for loading QML in Python, but my question is: why am I getting this syntax error? It's not even on the line I added.

- Linux x86_64 (also observed on ARM)
- Python v3.6.8
- PySide2 v5.13.0
- IDE: vim

Comment: Is that the entire traceback? How do you check that the script works?

Comment: That's the full traceback. I'm running with the command `$ python3 test.py`

Comment: Looks like there's a tab or spaces that got inserted into the front of the line, like if you typed without paying attention where the cursor was or something.

Comment: I thought the same thing, but then I tried opening a new file and re-typing the whole script, letter by letter. It's the same situation; that last line causes the syntax error.

Comment: @eyllanesc I edited the question and added my OS and IDE.

Comment: That's not what a Python syntax error looks like.

Comment: I just tried my own Arch machine; Python v3.7.3 with PySide v5.13.0, still seeing the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is *not* a Python syntax error as noted by @user2357112. The problem is that you are trying to load your Python source code as the QML URL:

```
qml_url = QUrl(sys.argv[0])
```

which is simply `PySide2.QtCore.QUrl('test.py')`.

The syntax error is raised by the `setSource` call, which tells that the first line is not valid QML.